# Magento get Zipcodes for a particular country and state

Tags: magento-1.9, countries, country-regions, zipcode

I am using Magento 1.9.x version for my website.

Now I am fectching the country list for storing country in a business directory.

I am able to fetch all the states of a particular country (US) when it is selected, by ajax, but now when any state is selected, I want a list(drop-down only) of zipcodes for the selected state, to appear right below the state dropdown.

**edit:**

**My question is how to fetch zipcodes list for a specific country and state, like web api**

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Default magento **does have this feature**.You **need to do customization for your requirement**.

- First create a custom module which have a custom table and custom
  model. At table,you need to save country id,region id and zipcodes
- Then, on change of region and country, call ajax which will given 
  list of zip code

Comment: My question is how to fetch zipcodes list for a specific country and state, like web api ?

Comment: From what I can tell, Magento does not have zip codes as part of its data.  You would have to find that information, store it in a custom table, then use your API to access that information.  There is a listing of countries, and Cities, but not zip codes.  So if you look in your database at the table directory_country_region you will see Countries, but no zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

As [Amit Bera](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/4564/amit-bera) said , there is no such feature in magento. You can achieve it by creating a custom module , with custom table where you need to save country_name , state_name , pin_code in it.

So wherever state field is coming on front-end , you need to create js onchange  function for that field to update in zip-code.

But before acheiving this you need the list of states for all countries & update them in DB.

There is no web api for retrieving pin code.